# Is it possible to define $\lceil x\rceil$ in terms of $\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have tried to define the ceiling function of $x$ in terms of its floor function; I thought this might be easy, but it isn't. I can easily do this with a piecewise equation, but I need to do without it.

## Attempts

I have tried three methods, one of which ($\mathbf{(3)}$) almost always works:

$$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+1\not= \left\lceil x\right\rceil,\tag 1$$
when $x=3$, because:
$$\left\lfloor 3\right\rfloor+1=4,\text{and }4\not=\lceil3\rceil.$$
$$\left\lfloor x+1\right\rfloor\not= \left\lceil x\right\rceil,\tag2$$
when $x=3$.
$$\left\lfloor x+\frac{x}{x+1}\right\rfloor\not= \left\lceil x\right\rceil,\tag3$$
when $\varepsilon$ is a number extremely close to $0$ and $x=(8+\varepsilon)$, i.e $x=8.099999999999987$. In that event:
$$\left\lfloor 8.099999999999987+\frac{8.099999999999987}{9.099999999999987}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor8.09999999999998+0.89010989010989\right\rfloor=\lfloor 8.99010989010987\rfloor=8,\text{and }8\not=\left\lceil8.099999999999987\right\rceil$$

## Question

Is it possible to define $\left\lceil\ldots\right\rceil$ in terms of $\left\lfloor \ldots\right\rfloor$?

Comment: How about $-\lfloor -x \rfloor$?

Comment: No continuous function $f(x)$ can satisfy $\lceil x \rceil = \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ for all $x$, because for integer $n$ we would have $f(n) < n+1$ but $\lim_{x \downarrow n} f(x) \geq n+1$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can calculate *ceiling* as:

$$\lceil{x}\rceil=-\lfloor{-x}\rfloor$$

---

You can calculate *floor* itself as:

$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=x-\frac12\left(\frac{\ln\left(e^{2\pi i\left(x-\frac12\right)}\right)}{\pi i}+1\right)$$

This is because $e^{2\pi i\left(x-\frac12\right)}$ has a period of $1$.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I'll accept when the time becomes available.

Comment: I don't understand the enthusiasm for this answer. The function is not even defined for integer values of $x$, let alone gives the right value. If you ignore the integers, then the equation $\lfloor x\rfloor +1 = \lceil x\rceil$ of the question would simply hold. Also the remark about negative $x$ are misplaced; the final term is perfectly $1$-periodic, so negative $x$ is no problem at all.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Most of the enthusiasm arises from the fact that Barak posted the $$ - \left\lceil -x \right\rfloor $$ response very quickly (which answers the question elegantly), not because of the second construction. Although it looks nice, Barak got about 6 upvotes before he edited that in.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Negative integers are a problem (in the trigonometric formula). The other negative values are not. When I wrote "doesn't necessarily yield the correct output for negative values of $x$", I did not mean **all** negative values, but only **some** of them (negative integers, as I just said).

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't see how positive integers would not pose the the same problem that negative integers do. As I said, the final term is perfectly periodic, it does not behave any different in the positive range from how it behaves in the negative range of$~x$. So the positive/negative distinction is a red herring. (And of course the first two terms are non-problematic.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I'm not sure what you mean by "last term" (arctan?), but I tested in Python, using `x+0.5+math.atan(-math.tan(math.pi*(x+0.5)))/math.pi`, and it seemed to yield correct output for all input except negative integers.

Comment: Your expression has three terms, separated (as terms are) by "$+$"; the third one is the fraction with $\pi$ in the denominator. It is undefined at _all_ integer values, because $\tan(y)$ is not defined whenever $y$ is an odd multiple (positive or negative) of $\frac\pi2$. Using Python (or any programming language) is not a valid method to determine whether a mathematical function is defined at some value; one cannot even represent $\pi$ precisely in floating point.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yep, I stand corrected. I derived it from a different formula, and must have made some mistake along the way. I've updated the answer to contain the original formula.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta: Please see revised answer.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Please see revised answer (fixed due to a comment by Mark van Leeuwen).

Comment: OK, the formula is correct now, at least if you are using the principal branch of the logarithm.

Comment: This is the type of stuff that makes me like math, just saying.

Answer (score 10):

*Well-known lemma*: $$ \left\lceil x \right\rceil = - \left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor $$*Proof.* Let $ x = a + k $, where $ a = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $. If $k=0$ the proof is trivial ,so let $ 0 < k < 1 $. Then, the LHS is $a+1$ and $$ \begin {align*} \text {RHS} &= - \left\lfloor - \left( a + k \right) \right\rfloor \\&= - \left\lfloor -a - k \right\rfloor \\&= - \left( -a - 1\right) \\&= a + 1. \end {align*} $$So we are done. $\Box$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\lceil x \rceil = -\lfloor-x\rfloor
$$

Comment: Have you read the other answers? ;)

Comment: Apparently I didn't.

Comment: @MichaelHardy +1 for honesty :)

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is infinitesimal positive number, and you assume that $\lceil{a}\rceil=1$, then...

$$\lfloor{x+1-a}\rfloor=\lceil{x}\rceil$$

Comment: This works in theory. My question was founded in practice. +1 anyhow.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Yeah, I just was trying to give you a solution based on your idea, and not just what is commonly known