# If $f(x)=\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$ and $g(x)=\left \lceil{x}\right \rceil$, express $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $x$.

Tags: proof-explanation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $f(x)=\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$ and $g(x)=\left \lceil{x}\right \rceil$, express $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $x$.

I am not too sure how to tackle this problem (I am new when it comes to these functions, so the simpler the solution the better!).

Looking at similar [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083878/is-it-possible-to-define-lceil-x-rceil-in-terms-of-lfloor-ldots-rfloor) $-\left \lfloor{-x}\right \rfloor$ seems to be the answer, but the answer from the book I am using says (sorry this is an image, but I am not confident to type it out!):

[image]

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's *possible* that the book wanted "express $\lceil x\rceil$ in terms of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $x$"  to mean "write the difference $\lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x\rfloor$ as a function of $x$" rather than "write the ceiling function in terms of the floor function." It's maybe more likely that the book's question is just poorly written and it's not clear what exactly they want - though their expression is, at least, *correct* if complicated.

Comment: It's a more complicated way to express the same. Note that $\lfloor y + k\rfloor = \lfloor y\rfloor + k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now move some integers into or out of the floor and cancel. But it has the advantage of showing that $\lceil x\rceil = \lfloor x\rfloor + 1$ unless $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Yeah, the book’s answer is needlessly complicated. NotE that $$\lfloor 1-x+\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor=1+\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor -x\rfloor$$